# Java: understanding Image Rasters

Tags: java, image

to my understanding the following code

```
int [] pixels = image.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, width, height, (int[])null);
```

should generate an array which has exactly the size width x height, but in practice it seems to be much larger, why?

image may be a bufferedimage, toolkitimage or volatileimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it generates a array with

```
new int[numBands * w * h]; // The number of bands of the image data.
```

from the `SampleModel` from your `Raster`

Comment: see [WritableRaster](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) and see [BandedSampleModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BandedSampleModel.html)  or [Here](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Supplements/Chapter11/bufferedImage.html)